# Which API should I use for sending snmpv3 trap

Tags: perl, snmp, cpan, net-snmp, snmpd

I am using perl module Net::SNMP to create snmpv3 session. Can you please let me know which api can be used to send snmpv3 trap.

I can see below information about `snmpv2_trap` api, so I think same cannot be used for sending snmpv3 trap

NOTE: This method can only be used when the version of the object is set to SNMPv2c. SNMPv2-Trap-PDUs are supported by SNMPv3, but require the sender of the message to be an authoritative SNMP engine which is not currently supported by the Net::SNMP module.

http://search.cpan.org/~dtown/Net-SNMP-v6.0.1/lib/Net/SNMP.pm